# Python Function that prints the number of words in a txt file and prints the first 10 words

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, printing

My code:

So far I've managed to print the whole text file in list format. However, I am now trying to get it to print the number of words along with the first 10 words in the file.

T

Comment: Please break down your code by explaining what it is that is not working in your current implementation. Explain what unexpected outputs or errors you are receiving for the provided input. You need to give the readers the relevant information per a good [mcve], in order for the reader to know how to quickly answer your question.

Comment: My apologies I'm new. There aren't any errors coming back, it's just printing every word in the file. It's not printing the first 10 words or the word count of the whole file.

Comment: What does your file look like exactly? Is it just each word on a single line?

Comment: Yes the text file just has one word per line

Comment: And the output has to be in what format? These are the information that is missing to help the readers know how to help. To make your question more complete just add information like what the file looks like, and how it should look like. Also add the small bit of information about what problem you are currently facing in your question.

Comment: The output just needs to be the same, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the amount of words in the file, and the first ten words (if the file is not ten words long, it will print as many as it can):

```
def get_dictionary_wordlist():
    return open('dictionary.txt','r').read()

def test_get_dictionary_wordlist():
    text = get_dictionary_wordlist()
    textlist = text.split(" ")
    print("No. of Words: " + str(len(textlist)))
    try:
        for word in range(0,10):
            print(textlist[word])
    except:
        pass

test_get_dictionary_wordlist()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in range(N):
    f.readline()
```

Comment: Incorrect and zero explanation. Please don't get into the habit of answering like this - make sure your answers are *correct* and explain to the OP *why* it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593) [The same goes for incorrect answers.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/2747593)